# openrdf Sesame: Is it possible to parse single lines?

Tags: java, parsing, rdf, sesame

Is it possible to use the parsers from the openrdf framework to parse single lines of text into the openrdf model?
I would like to to parse huge nquads files and would like to use the

```
org.openrdf.rio.nquads.NQuadsParser
```

for this task. My dream solution would return an `org.openrdf.model.Statement`, with proper instances of subject, predicate, object and context. I know the class itself does not have a method to do this.
Since I try to parse very big files, I can not load them completely into a repository. I could probably parse chunks of the file into a repository, evaluate and then clear the repository, making room for the next chunk.
I am wondering if there is a better way to get Statements from lines of a text file?

For some context, I want to gather statistics on [Huge Nquads Files](http://km.aifb.kit.edu/projects/btc-2012/), for which I need to evaluate each statement, but do not need to store the majority of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to parse single lines AFAIK but Sesame does have an API that allows you to control what is done with parsed statements which would avoid the need for your code to actually store statements into a repository.

See the [documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#chapter-rio2) for a simple example of just counting triples but you can easily do much more complex processing this way.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this possibility. For my use case, this might be even better than a line-by-line parser!

Comment: Maybe I was too quick :) I am aware that I can set VERIFY_DATATYPE_VALUES and FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_DATATYPES as non-fatal, but my data is very noisy. Is there a way to just skip completely unparsable (e.g. not even rdf) lines? Instead the parsing fails completely.

Comment: That'd be a question for the Sesame developers but AFAIK no you can't

Answer (score 2):

Upon further investigation, I realized that there are more ParserSettings apart from the ones in

```
org.openrdf.rio.helpers.BasicParserSettings
```

Specifically, the

```
NTriplesParserSettings.FAIL_ON_NTRIPLES_INVALID_LINES
```

can prevent a parser from failing when discovering invalid lines. E.g. setting

```
parser.getParserConfig().addNonFatalError(NTriplesParserSettings.FAIL_ON_NTRIPLES_INVALID_LINES);
```

will configure your parser to be more error-tolerant. This allows to parse the 'good' triples in a noisy nquads/ntriples file.

Comment: This is definitely the use case for FAIL_ON_NTRIPLES_INVALID_LINES!